# EBS volume for m4.large not ebsOptimized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

M4 large instances are EBS-optimized by default as per below URL :

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

When I try to check the status using aws-cli I get result with boolean value set to false. The command I used is as below :

ec2-describe-instance-attribute i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --ebs-optimized --aws-access-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --aws-secret-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Result of above command :

ebsOptimized    i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     false

Is it the correct way to verify if the instance is EBS optimized? Please help me to verify if the instance is EBS optimized.

Answer (score 0):

See the command and output below:

```
[root@ip-172-1-1-1 ~]# aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --region eu-west-1  --instance-id xxxxxxxxx --attribute ebsOptimized
{
    "InstanceId": "i-003069xxxxxxxxx",
    "EbsOptimized": {
        "Value": true
    }
}
```

You can also see this from aws console reflecting as below:

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying. For me cli and console both show EBS-optimized set to False.[root@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx ~]# aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --region us-east-1  --instance-id i-xxxxxxxx --attribute ebsOptimized                {
    "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxx",
    "EbsOptimized": {
        "Value": false
    }
}

Comment: What you could do is, stop the ec2 instance and select `change instance type` from `instance setting`, tick the box to enable it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I figured out that the instance was created using Auto-scaling group which had Launch configuration with the EBS-Optimized option unchecked.